# How to fill up the empty space left by the column using the width?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

[image]

I want each columns to have the same size to fill up the empty space one and I'm still new to bootstrap so I need some help with it

```
 <div class="container-fluid mt-3 position-absolute top-50">
        <div class="Header ">
            <h1>Project Cat</h1>
        </div>
         <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4 gap-3 bg-transparent-30 underline">
             <div class="col fs-1">Colum1</div>
             <div class="col fs-1">Colum2</div>
             <div class="col fs-1">Colum3</div>
       </div>
</div>
```

There are a lot of things that I tried to make the columns to have the same size and fill up the empty space but since I'm new to this none of my solution works so I'm going to appreciate it if someone help help me how to fix it and teach me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking it.  Just have a `row` and inside of that three `col`'s.

Read up on how the bootstrap grid system works here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/

```css
.fs-1{background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
     <div class="row gap-3">
         <div class="col fs-1">Colum1</div>
         <div class="col fs-1">Colum2</div>
         <div class="col fs-1">Colum3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```